# Tish'a Veshishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mentioned in the name of the Sefer Yetzira that the average of the Gematria of Nisan, Iyar, and Sivan = 169

Nisan = 170

Iyar = 221

Sivan = 126

170 + 221 + 126 = 517 divided by 3 = 169

Comment: Why is this mentioned in Sefer Y'tzira?

Answer (score 1):

The Jewish Chronicle is the world's oldest Jewish newspaper and has been running for 169 years

Answer (score 1):

> Since ours is the seventh parshah and
>   all sevenths are endeared, let us
>   continue this idea and look at the
>   seventh word of the parshah. The
>   seventh word is the first word of the
>   second verse, ויפגע , which is usually
>   translated as “He [Jacob] arrived,”
>   but more literally it means “He hit
>   upon [the place],”or “He collided with
>   [the place].” The gematria of the
>   seventh word ויפגע is 169 = 13 x 13, where
>   13 is the gematria of “one” אחד , and
>   “love” אהבה .

http://www.inner.org/parshah/genesis/vayeitzei/E68-0301.php